# How to save changes in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm recently working on a project which allows you to deposit, withdraw and create new accounts. I want to know if I can somehow save the changes after rerunning the code, for example, the change of users. I've tried several ways on the internet and they didn't seem to work.

Comment: Click on the question mark inside the circle that appears in the top right corner of this Web page. It opens a drop-down menu with some links. I suggest you visit those links. It will help you to get answers to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to accomplish this. For a new programmer, I'd suggest learning how to [read and write from files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) to start.

A simple database system is also an option, but probably more complicated than what you're looking for. This also can't be covered in one tutorial. If you're interested, you should probably do your own research and find something that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a database system.
In short, the database will store the data. Your program reads and displays that data. The user modifies it, and pass it to your program to "save" the data (which is replaced the old data with new ones in the database)